# Does the MongoDb TTL index monitor block?

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing, ttl

Is the automatic removal of documents based on a TTL index a blocking operation?  The mongo docs don't seem to say one way or the other (or I was unable to glean the info from it).

A pointer to the right spot in the docs would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it must take read lock for a microsecond to retrieve the document from the index and then it must take write lock to delete the document

Comment: But reads are concurrent